# FQDN Validation

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm new to programming, I'd like you to check my work and criticize the hell out of me.  What would you do differently?

FQDN: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name

- 253 characters not including trailing dot
- Label1.Label2.Label3.adomain.com
- All labels must be between 1-63 characters
- Cannot start or end with hyphen (-)
- May contain only a-z, 0-9 and hyphens

This just checks to make sure the hostname passed as an argument meets all standards.

```
import re


def is_fqdn(hostname):
    """
    :param hostname: string
    :return: bool
    """
    #  Remove trailing dot
    try:  # Is this necessary?
        if hostname[-1] == '.':
            hostname = hostname[0:-1]
    except IndexError:
        return False

    #  Check total length of hostname < 253
    if len(hostname) > 253:
        return False

    #  Split hostname into list of DNS labels
    hostname = hostname.split('.')

    #  Define pattern of DNS label
    #  Can begin and end with a number or letter only
    #  Can contain hyphens, a-z, A-Z, 0-9
    #  1 - 63 chars allowed
    fqdn = re.compile(r'^[a-z0-9]([a-z-0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?$', re.IGNORECASE)

    #  Check if length of each DNS label < 63
    #  Match DNS label to pattern
    for label in hostname:
        if len(label) > 63:
            return False
        if not fqdn.match(label):
            return False

    #  Found no errors, returning True
    return True
```

I declared the variable for the regex pattern after the 2 conditionals with return statements.  My thought was, why store a variable that would be unused if the prior conditions were met?

Could the regex be written any better?

Comment: Your code looks good so far. Have you already written some unit tests for it? Using [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) this is really simple. This way you can check yourself whether the `try` block is really necessary. If you have unit tests, you should add them to your question. And if you don't have any tests, just provide a list of names and whether each of them is valid or not.

Comment: This is tangentially related to your question, but just to make sure you cover all the bases you may want to have a look at IDN (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comments:

1. Use type declarations!  These are (IMO) easier to read than docstring comments and they also make your code `mypy`-able.
2. Your `try/catch` block is just an indirect way of requiring that the parameter is at least 1 character long.  It's more clear IMO to just check the length explicitly, especially since you're already doing that as the next step.
3. Reassigning a different type to an existing variable is something you see a lot in quick-and-dirty Python scripts, but it's bad practice IMO (and mypy will treat it as an error unless you forward-declare it with a tricky `Union` type).  Just use a new variable name when you generate a new object with a new type.
4. Your regex already enforces the 63-character requirement.  DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)!
5. Using Python's built-in `all` function is better than rolling your own `for` loop.

```
import re

def is_fqdn(hostname: str) -> bool:
    """
    https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name
    """
    if not 1 < len(hostname) < 253:
        return False

    # Remove trailing dot
    if hostname[-1] == '.':
        hostname = hostname[0:-1]

    #  Split hostname into list of DNS labels
    labels = hostname.split('.')

    #  Define pattern of DNS label
    #  Can begin and end with a number or letter only
    #  Can contain hyphens, a-z, A-Z, 0-9
    #  1 - 63 chars allowed
    fqdn = re.compile(r'^[a-z0-9]([a-z-0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?$', re.IGNORECASE)

    # Check that all labels match that pattern.
    return all(fqdn.match(label) for label in labels)
```

I echo Roland's suggestion about writing a unit test.  A function like this is really easy to write tests for; you'd do it like:

```
def test_is_fqdn() -> None:
    # Things that are FQDNs
    assert is_fqdn("homestarrunner.net")
    assert is_fqdn("zombo.com")

    # Things that are not FQDNs
    assert not is_fqdn("")
    assert not is_fqdn("a*")
    assert not is_fqdn("foo")  # no TLD means it's not a FQDN!
```

Note that the last assert in that test will fail...

Comment: This is exactly what I needed Sam.  Thank you for helping me learn!  I thought by creating a new variable for a list when I could just reassign would be a waste of resources.

Comment: You're creating the new object in memory regardless.  :)

Since you only use the list once, you could also just not name it, e.g. `return all(fqdn.match(label) for label in hostname.split('.'))`

Comment: Note that `foo` is a perfectly valid FQDN: it resolves to the host named `foo` in the root domain, i.e. it is equivalent to `foo.`. There is an example of a small island country offering exactly that: Tonga sold an A record for `to` to a URI shortener service for some time. See https://serverfault.com/a/90753/1499 and https://superuser.com/q/78408/2571

Answer (score 4):

Your requirements could be summed up in a single regex.

```py
import re

def is_fqdn(hostname):
    return re.match(r'^(?!.{255}|.{253}[^.])([a-z0-9](?:[-a-z-0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?\.)*[a-z0-9](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?[.]?$', hostname, re.IGNORECASE)
```

I don't particularly condone this very condensed formulation; but this does everything in your requirements.

Here's a rundown.

- `^` beginning of line / expression
- `(?!.{255}|.{253}[^.])` negative lookahead: don't permit 255 or more characters, or 254 where the last is not a dot.
- `([a-z0-9](?:[-a-z-0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?\.)*` zero or more labels where the first and last characters are not hyphen, and a max of 61 characters between them can also be a hyphen; all followed by a dot. The last 62 are optional so that we also permit a single-character label where the first character is also the last.
- `[a-z0-9](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?` the final label does not have to be followed by a dot
- `[.]?` but it can be
- `$` end of line / expression

When you only use a regex once, there is no acute reason to `compile` it. Python will do this under the hood anyway (and in fact keep a cache of recently used compiled regexes and often reuse them more quickly than if you explicitly recompile).

Comment: So what you’re saying is, just to clarify, that single regex could replace all of my code. However, it isn’t a good practice. Correct me if I’m wrong please.

Comment: I'm sort of divided on "good practice". In a complex program where you use a lot of regex for other stuff, this would not at all be out of place.

Comment: re.error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 64

Comment: @shikida Thanks for the feedback! Belatedly fixed and tested. (Good thing I wrote notes, or it would have been kind of hard to second-guess what this was supposed to do. That's one of the problems with it.)